# BuildAgent working directory in distributed environment

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I've got a build controller running 2 Agents (Agent1, Agent2) on the same machine. 
I've installed another build agent (Agent3) on a different machine inside the same AD.

Now when it comes to Agent3 I get the error, that Agent3 can not access the share on \buildagentmachine\Build.

Agent1 and Agent2 have working directories:
D:\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
(where D:\Builds is the local folder on the build controller which is shared via network).

Agent3's working directory is:
$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
on its local hard drive.

Now whats funny beside: On the build controller computer I get the following folders under D:\Builds:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- ProjectName

Looks like Agent3 is putting all its stuff directly under \controller\Builds which means, write access is enabled for the agent.

Comment: Is the build controller on a separate machine than the 2 machines running your agents?

Comment: No. Build controller and the Agents 1 and 2 are on same machine.

Comment: Try deleting the 3 folder from the build controller and see if the agent recreates it on there.  Also make sure you don't have any additional agents running on your build controller server.  It's possible that 3 folder is just left over from a previously configured agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is about accessing a share, are you sure it's not erroring out when the build tries to copy the build outputs to the build drop share?  Make sure the user account that build agent 3 is configured to run as is the same as the one used for build agents 1 and 2.  You can check this in the TFS Admin console on the build agent machines.